# Imaging a Windows 7 system to run with a specific account

Tags: windows-7, sysprep, imagex

I am using the Microsoft imaging and sysprep tools to create an image which shall run, after copying to a disk, with a specific user. Call it userx.  This user shall be configured with customisations in the registry. For example one customisation is concerned with tablet configuration in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

What is the best way to do this?  Do I setup the user in my image and then when setting up login as that user, apply the customisations and then sysprep? Will these customisations be saved after doing the oobe (out of box experience / generalising)?

Or will the customisations be lost after running oobe?

What about customisations such as screen resolution? If I login  as this user, userx, and set screen resolution to something, then will this customisation be present after oobe?

When running an image created using ImageX, Windows 7 logs in as administrator. This is a separate account. If I set copyprofile=true in Microsoft-Windows-Shell_Setup_neutral section of the unattended answer file used, will it over-write my customisations?  In which set copyprofile=false?

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyProfile` setting only causes Sysprep to move a certain user's (usually the Administrator's) personal settings into the default account so that *all new* accounts on the machine get those settings. **The Sysprep generalization procedure preserves user accounts** unless you intentionally torch them in audit mode and generalize from there. Therefore, if you only need one user's settings to be as you configured, you don't need to worry about `CopyProfile`. OOBE requires you to create a new user account, but you'll always be able to log in as other users; all their personal stuff will be intact.

Further reading at TechNet: [`CopyProfile`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825135.aspx), [generalizing with Sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824938.aspx)